# indented unordered list to nested list()

Tags: r, list, parsing

I've got a log file that looks as follows:

```
Data:
 +datadir=/data/2017-11-22
 +Nusers=5292
Parameters:
 +outdir=/data/2017-11-22/out
 +K=20
 +IC=179
 +ICgroups=3
   -group 1: 1-1
    ICeffects: 1-5
   -group 2: 2-173
    ICeffects: 6-10
   -group 3: 175-179
    ICeffects: 11-15
```

I would like to parse this logfile into a nested list using R so that the result will look like this:

```
result <- list(Data = list(datadir = '/data/2017-11-22',
                           Nusers = 5292),
               Parameters = list(outdir = '/data/2017-11-22/out',
                                 K = 20,
                                 IC = 179,
                                 ICgroups = list(list('group 1' = '1-1',
                                                      ICeffects = '1-5'),
                                                      list('group 2' = '2-173',
                                                      ICeffects = '6-10'),
                                                      list('group 1' = '175-179',
                                                      ICeffects = '11-15'))))
```

Is there a not-extremely-painful way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: This is messy. There is no guarantee that this will work for larger/different files without some tweaking. You will need to do some careful checking.

The key idea here is to reformat the raw data, to make it consistent with the YAML format, and then use `yaml::yaml.load` to parse the data to produce a nested list.

By the way, this is an excellent example on why one really should use a common markup language for log-output/config files (like JSON, YAML, etc.)...

I assume you read in the log file using `readLines` to produce the vector of strings `ss`.

```
# Sample data
ss <- c(
    "Data:",
    " +datadir=/data/2017-11-22",
    " +Nusers=5292",
    "Parameters:",
    " +outdir=/data/2017-11-22/out",
    " +K=20",
    " +IC=179",
    " +ICgroups=3",
    "   -group 1: 1-1",
    "    ICeffects: 1-5",
    "   -group 2: 2-173",
    "    ICeffects: 6-10",
    "   -group 3: 175-179",
    "    ICeffects: 11-15")
```

We then reformat the data to adhere to the YAML format.

```
# Reformat to adhere to YAML formatting
ss <- gsub("\\+", "- ", ss);                   # Replace "+" with "- "
ss <- gsub("ICgroups=\\d+","ICgroups:", ss);   # Replace "ICgroups=3" with "ICgroups:"
ss <- gsub("=", " : ", ss);                    # Replace "=" with ": "
ss <- gsub("-group", "- group", ss);           # Replace "-group" with "- group"
ss <- gsub("ICeffects", " ICeffects", ss);     # Replace "ICeffects" with " ICeffects"
```

Note that – consistent with your expected output – the value `3` from `ICgroups` doesn't get used, and we need to replace `ICgroups=3` with `ICgroups:` to initiate a nested sub-list. This was the part that threw me off first...

Loading & parsing the YAML string then produces a nested list.

```
require(yaml);
lst <- yaml.load(paste(ss, collapse = "\n"));
lst;

#$Data
#$Data[[1]]
#$Data[[1]]$datadir
#[1] "/data/2017-11-22"
#
#
#$Data[[2]]
#$Data[[2]]$Nusers
#[1] 5292
#
#
#
#$Parameters
#$Parameters[[1]]
#$Parameters[[1]]$outdir
#[1] "/data/2017-11-22/out"
#
#
#$Parameters[[2]]
#$Parameters[[2]]$K
#[1] 20
#
#
#$Parameters[[3]]
#$Parameters[[3]]$IC
#[1] 179
#
#
#$Parameters[[4]]
#$Parameters[[4]]$ICgroups
#$Parameters[[4]]$ICgroups[[1]]
#$Parameters[[4]]$ICgroups[[1]]$`group 1`
#[1] "1-1"
#
#$Parameters[[4]]$ICgroups[[1]]$ICeffects
#[1] "1-5"
#
#
#$Parameters[[4]]$ICgroups[[2]]
#$Parameters[[4]]$ICgroups[[2]]$`group 2`
#[1] "2-173"
#
#$Parameters[[4]]$ICgroups[[2]]$ICeffects
#[1] "6-10"
#
#
#$Parameters[[4]]$ICgroups[[3]]
#$Parameters[[4]]$ICgroups[[3]]$`group 3`
#[1] "175-179"
#
#$Parameters[[4]]$ICgroups[[3]]$ICeffects
#[1] "11-15"
```

PS. You will need to test this on larger files, and make changes to the substitution if necessary.

Comment: Clever! And yes, I'm still tripping up over the `ICgroups` so if you've got an easy solution to that, that'd be much appreciated

Comment: @RoyalTS I can now parse the full example data that you give, please take a look at my updated solution. This will most likely need some tweaking for larger/different log files, but this is the best I can come up with. The alternative would be to write your own parser...