# flatten nested list at every level

Tags: r, list

I've got a nested list that looks like so:

```
> spec

$Data[[1]]
$Data[[1]]$Nusers
[1] 5292

$Data[[2]]
$Data[[2]]$Nitems
[1] 4890

$Data[[3]]
$Data[[3]]$Nsessions
[1] 45618

...

$Parameters[[4]]
$Parameters[[4]]$ICgroups
$Parameters[[4]]$ICgroups[[1]]
$Parameters[[4]]$ICgroups[[1]]$group_1
$Parameters[[4]]$ICgroups[[1]]$group_1[[1]]
$Parameters[[4]]$ICgroups[[1]]$group_1[[1]]$ICidx
[1] "1-1"

$Parameters[[4]]$ICgroups[[1]]$group_1[[2]]
$Parameters[[4]]$ICgroups[[1]]$group_1[[2]]$ICeffects
[1] "1-5"

$Parameters[[4]]$ICgroups[[1]]$group_1[[3]]
$Parameters[[4]]$ICgroups[[1]]$group_1[[3]]$ICeffectsPrice
[1] "1-3"

$Parameters[[4]]$ICgroups[[2]]
$Parameters[[4]]$ICgroups[[2]]$group_2
$Parameters[[4]]$ICgroups[[2]]$group_2[[1]]
$Parameters[[4]]$ICgroups[[2]]$group_2[[1]]$ICidx
[1] "2-173"

$Parameters[[4]]$ICgroups[[2]]$group_2[[2]]
$Parameters[[4]]$ICgroups[[2]]$group_2[[2]]$ICeffects
[1] "6-10"

$Parameters[[4]]$ICgroups[[2]]$group_2[[3]]
$Parameters[[4]]$ICgroups[[2]]$group_2[[3]]$ICeffectsPrice
[1] "4-6"
```

I would like to flatten this list at every level so that I could access e.g. `spec$Parameters$ICgroups$group_1$ICidx` but my `purrr` fu is failing me.

Answer (score 1):

What about using `plyr::llply` with `unlist`?

I'm using `lst` from my solution to [your previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47735682/indented-unordered-list-to-nested-list/47737705#47737705).

```
require(plyr);
llply(lst, unlist)
#$Data
#           datadir             Nusers
#"/data/2017-11-22"             "5292"
#
#$Parameters
#                outdir                      K                     IC
#"/data/2017-11-22/out"                   "20"                  "179"
#      ICgroups.group 1     ICgroups.ICeffects       ICgroups.group 2
#                 "1-1"                  "1-5"                "2-173"
#    ICgroups.ICeffects       ICgroups.group 3     ICgroups.ICeffects
#                "6-10"              "175-179"                "11-15"
```

Comment: I'm not so eager on loading `plyr` -- it sometimes masks the tidyverse functions. More importantly though, this flattens the list at the second level completely. I want to maintain the tree structure, just get rid of the unnecessary levels.

Comment: @RoyalTS Fair enough. In that case, could you please clarify what are the "unnecessary levels"? Also, I would suggest accepting my answer to your previous question to formally close the previous question.

Comment: @RoyalTS, if this is the output you're after, then maybe you can just use `lapply(lst, unlist)` instead of having to load plyr.